# Mapping changes in elasticsearch 2.3.3

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

How can we set limit of nested fields in ES index in elasticsearch 2.3.3 manually which is 50 by default?

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Limit of nested fields [50] in index [1000] has been exceeded"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mentioned in the [breaking changes for 2.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-2.3.html#breaking_23_index_apis):

You can change this in your index settings with the the following:

```
index.mapping.nested_fields.limit: 1001
```

Note that this is only taken into account when an index is created or mappings are updated.